# PHP split set of dates into range in the sequence order

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am struggling with sleepless nights without knowing how to do this or finding a good example.
I have a php array which contains dates, lets say `dateArray`, dates in the array may be in sequence order or may not, and number of date elements in the array varies for different situation.
I want to make a new array of array from my `dateArray` which will contain all the possible date ranges which should be built by the date sequence order.

For example if my `dateArray` contain elements (dd-mm-yy)

```
2018-01-01,2018-01-02,2018-01-03,2018-01-05,2018-01-06
```

The news array i expected should should have following result.

```
0 ==> 2018-01-01,2018-01-03/
1 ==> 2018-01-05,2018-01-06
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this function, it accept dates array as argument and it will return date range from array of dates, note that return value is an array,

```
    function getDateRangeSplitted($dates)
{
    sort($dates);
    $startDate  = $dates[0];
    $finishDate = array_pop($dates);
    // walk through the dates, breaking at gaps
    foreach ($dates as $key => $date)
        if (($key > 0) && (strtotime($date)-strtotime($dates[$key-1]) > 99999)) {
            $result[] = array($startDate,$dates[$key-1]);
            $startDate = $date;
        }
    // force the end
    $result[] = array($startDate,$finishDate);
    return $result;
}
```

reference: https://www.techalyst.com/links/read/122/laravel-php-split-all-possible-date-ranges-from-a-set-of-dates-by-consecutive-date-order